# rotating text in IE within an SVG

Tags: css, svg, chartist.js

I am using the chartist framework to create some charts, and I would like to rotate the x-axis labels.

Unfortunately, my solution doesn't work in ie11. Please see the fiddle below.

https://jsbin.com/zusofijave/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Any ideas would be welcome

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.ct-label.ct-label.ct-horizontal {
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: right;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: translate(-100%) rotate(-45deg);
  display: inline-block;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(0,0);
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#chart svg {
  overflow: visible;
}

.rotate{
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(0,0);
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: SVG animations say they aren't supported with this utility in IE11: https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/

Comment: Thanks, Im not trying to animate anything just rotate the text. The jsbin include an example of rotated text